# D3 can't load custom geojson data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm trying to load a custom [geojson file](http://geojson.io/#id=gist:Bloemenstraat/7b5c2bcf7d532a8345a386ff31b55f5c&map=5/28.710/4.263) I made using geojson.io, and here is the result :

[image]

When I use a another geojson, the data loads perfectly, but the custom ones seem to never work, so I infere that the code is clean. Am I misusing the geojson.io site ?
Here is the code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="./d3/d3.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <title>Squalalaa ! Nous sommes partis !</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        var h = 600, w = 500;
        var projection = d3.geoAlbersUsa().translate([w/2, h/2]).scale(600);
        //var projection = d3.geoMercator().scale(1000).translate([w/2, h+300]);

        var path = d3.geoPath(projection);
        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("height", h).attr("width", w).style("stroke", "black");
        //svg.append("circle").attr("cx", 20).attr("cy", 20).attr("r", 10);

        d3.json("map.geojson").then (function(json){
            console.log(json);
            svg.selectAll("path").data(json.features).enter().append("path").attr("d", path).style("fill", "blue");
        });
        </script>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add the geojson pictured above to the question?

Comment: The geojson file is available when you click the link on my first sentence.

Comment: Crabos, my bad - was distracted at the time.

Comment: Ok, my apologies. Didn't end up having much time free today, so I'll just use a comment here: the projection needs to not be an AlbersUsa projection: your features are not in or near the US. Try a generic projection, and center it on your features: `var projection = d3.geoMercator().fitSize([w,h],geojson);`

Comment: The winding order matters as you are dealing with spherical coordinates, the inside of the feature isn't known, if all are wound the wrong way you can use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54947126/7106086), otherwise, you might need another library, as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49311001/7106086).

Comment: Thank you very much, very detailed answers, I appreciate it !
The only problem that's left now is when I use turf the same way you did, I get the same strange error : Error: <reverse> must be a boolean
I'm pretty sure true is a boolean...