# Features aren't visualized correctly using fitSize function

Tags: d3.js, geospatial, geojson, topojson

I try to create a map of municipalities using D3 and a TopoJSON file. The problem I have is that the features aren't visualized correctly. The features are very small and cluttered.

I have tried to fix it using the `fitSize` function, but I didn't succeed.
The features *are* visualized correctly when I use this code:

```
let projection = d3.geoMercator()
    .center([6.6314,53.3423])
    .scale(30060)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
```

But I still would like to know why it isn't working with `fitSize`.

I use fitSize as so:

```
let projection = d3.geoMercator().fitSize([900, 600], topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.gemeenten));
```

Which results in a map like this:

[image]

This is my example code: http://bl.ocks.org/FrieseWoudloper/7f8634088803206fca6330c7658bf8b8

Comment: You have a winding order problem, d3 uses spherical math and doesn't "know" what side of the polygon is supposed to be the inside of the polygon, it makes one side the inside based on winding order. To resolve, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49311001/7106086) (*if you have mixed winding orders, as in your case. Otherwise you could rewind all the polygons as in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54949383/7106086), a modified second option would be to see if each polygon intersects something like the south pole and rewind these features only).

Comment: You can see the winding order causing features to be inverted because the map has a border that you didn't specify: this is the edge of the features that are inverted.

Comment: @AndrewReid Thank you very much for your answer!