# D3 - Attempting to Project Polygon Creates MultiPolygon leading to SVG Creation Failure

Tags: d3.js, map-projections

I am using the command line tools from the [d3-geo-projection](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo-projection) library to try and create some SVGs of some polygons that I have data for. It is not working consistently for me. In the instances where it doesn't work my polygon appears to be projected to a multipolygon.

Given this geojson saved in a file called test.json:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"fill":"#beaed4"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-122.8894617071551,38.6364492814026],[-122.9101318421297,38.59984250673184],[-122.8738456639462,38.5445037653864],[-122.8049438241416,38.49530288189208],[-122.7270519000589,38.49566238489009],[-122.7739678974201,38.56932074687278],[-122.8646575459043,38.64183105490673],[-122.8894617071551,38.6364492814026]]]}}]}
```

I am running:

`geoproject 'd3.geoMercator().fitSize([300, 250], d)' test.json > projected.json`

The output is (notice the two items in the coordinates array:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": { "fill": "#beaed4" },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [274.9999999999476, 0],
            [274.9999999999476, 5.102630758076188],
            [274.9999999999476, 32.77822486285348],
            [274.9999999999476, 60.74553203418762],
            [274.9999999999476, 89.93125922876354],
            [274.9999999999476, 108.95719291049969],
            [274.9999999999476, 124.99999999994759],
            [274.9999999999476, 141.0428070893955],
            [274.9999999999476, 160.06874077113164],
            [274.9999999999476, 189.2544679657076],
            [274.9999999999476, 249.99999999989518],
            [274.9999999999476, 249.99999999989518],
            [25.00000000005241, 249.99999999989518],
            [25.00000000005241, 250],
            [25.00000000005241, 189.2544679657076],
            [25.00000000005241, 160.06874077113164],
            [25.00000000005241, 141.0428070893955],
            [25.00000000005241, 124.99999999994759],
            [25.00000000005241, 108.95719291049969],
            [25.00000000005241, 89.93125922876354],
            [25.00000000005241, 60.74553203418762],
            [25.00000000005241, 32.77822486285348],
            [25.00000000005241, 5.102630758076188],
            [25.00000000005241, 0],
            [25.00000000005241, 0],
            [274.9999999999476, 0],
            [274.9999999999476, 0]
          ],
          [
            [64.66009603673362, 95.86882663178713],
            [64.6457417763346, 95.90136295448485],
            [64.67094051118424, 95.95051687576989],
            [64.71878901104853, 95.99418716973555],
            [64.77288062499483, 95.99386818608798],
            [64.74030007127179, 95.92847819504618],
            [64.67732114871333, 95.8640418783208],
            [64.66009603673362, 95.86882663178713]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If I then try to create an SVG from this output using:

`geo2svg -w 300 -h 250 < projected.json > test.svg`

I get (notice little tiny dot in the upper left quadrant:

[image: Actual]

This is what the polygon shape should look like:

[image: What it should look like]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a winding order issue. As D3 uses spherical geometry the winding order changes, for example, whether you draw one city or every part of the planet except that city. The latter is probably happening in your screenshot - the square is the edge of the world in that projection, the little dot is a hole in it representing what you actually want to draw. The solution is to rewind offending polytongs. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49311001/7106086) or this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54947126/7106086) should help.

Comment: As for why you get what appears to be a multipolygon after projecting - it isn't. It is still a polygon, just one with a hole. The first set of coordinates in a polygon represent an outer ring, and the subsequent sets represents holes in in the polygon (inner rings). Which further suggests a winding order issue.

Comment: @AndrewReid I used https://observablehq.com/@bumbeishvili/rewind-geojson to confirm the winding issue. Thank you for your help. Now to rewind all my polygons as a first step in cleaning up the data I think.

Comment: I ended up using https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-rewind as a pre-processing step and now everything is working.

Comment: I just spent hours banging my head against this with exports from https://mapshaper.org/ - and then attempting to project them in D3. Thank you.