# D3 Chloropleth Map Stops After Rendering One Region

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson, topojson

I'm trying to create a chloropleth map of Morocco in D3, colored differently based on population density. Currently, it renders the first region in the GeoJson, but thats the only thing it renders. This is the part where I load and render:

```
d3.csv("moroccoCSV.csv", function(data) {

        //Set input domain for color scale
        color.domain([
            d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.popDensity; }), 
            d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.popDensity; })
        ]);    

        var url = "Morocco.json";
        d3.json(url, function(geojson) {

            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                            //Grab state name
                            var dataState = data[i].region;

                            //Grab data value, and convert from string to float
                            var dataValue = parseFloat(data[i].popDensity);

                            //Find the corresponding state inside the GeoJSON
                            for (var j = 0; j < geojson.features.length; j++) {

                                var jsonState = geojson.features[j].properties.NAME_1;

                                if (dataState == jsonState) {

                                    //Copy the data value into the JSON
                                    geojson.features[j].properties.value = dataValue;

                                    //Stop looking through the JSON
                                    break;

                                }
                            }       
                        }
        svg.selectAll("path")
           .data(geojson.features)
           .enter()
           .append("path")
           .attr("d", path)
            .style("stroke", "black")
           .style("fill", function(d) {
                //Get data value
                var value = d.properties.value;

                if (value) {
                    //If value exists…
                    return color(value);
                } else {
                    //If value is undefined…
                    return "#ccc";
                }
           });
        });
    });
```

The console registers the values of each region, and their path as well, but does not render them. Also, if I replace .attr("d", path) with .attr("d", path(geojson), the map prints all the regions but they are all of the same fill color.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share a link to your Morocco geojson?

Comment: All the code is here: https://github.com/gabevandesande/MoroccoPopDensity

Comment: Using your code I get a rectangle of color which is indicative of a winding order problem, I'd take a look at [this (vanilla JS)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54949383/7106086) or [this (with turf.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49311635/7106086). Lastly, your code in the question is right: it is `path`, not `path(geojson)`: the first draws pass the current datum (single feature) to the path generator, the 2nd passes all features to the `path` generator for every datum: you'll draw Morocco many times, each time the same color.

Comment: Here's the turf [solution](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/be6785edeb32d6702851a86e35e5f4a3) - if it's working for you I may close as a duplicate.