# D3 GeoJSON only render partial map in rectangle

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, geojson

Currently I'm working a D3 project to render map with GeoJSON. I found this great example online https://bl.ocks.org/john-guerra/43c7656821069d00dcbc

and trying to implement with my GeoJSON map, while when I edited parameters according to new JSON file, the html only rendered partial map and showing in a rectangle. I tried to inspect the code but no clue where is wrong. Please share some hints where I can get the map display correctly. Full codes can be found on git https://github.com/gracemagy/singapore-map-D3

Thank you in advance!

Here is the code where I edited from original script:

updated targeted JSON file name

```
d3.json('electoral-boundary-dataset.geo.json', function(error, mapData) {
  var features = mapData.features;
```

d.properties.NOMBRE_DPT to d.properties.Name

```
function nameFn(d){
  return d && d.properties ? d.properties.Name : null;
}
```

scale(1500) to scale(50) to zoom out the map

```
var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
  .scale(50)
```

Comment: You have a winding issue - normally this isn't a problem, most libraries use planar coordinates which means there is only one way to wind a polygon so that it is closed. D3 uses spherical geometry, there are two ways to wind each polygon. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49311001/7106086) for a solution, or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54947126/7106086) for a more manual one that requires a bit of tweaking for your example. Alternatively, finding a new geojson is an option as in the answer below.

Comment: [Here's](https://gist.github.com/Andrew-Reid/62986e2285e730347dbb9eb256c299f5) an example adapting the first solution to your map (with appropriate scale and centering on the map - with scale 50 you won't see your features unless adding a stroke width).

Comment: @AndrewReid Yes you're absolutely right that it's a winding issue. I can populate the map with the sample you shared. :D

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like there might be a problem with your geoJSON. <s>It's like it has a frame around the map, and maybe that's the square you are looking at. If you make the fill of your example "none" and draw the stroke, you can see that your map is looking tiny inside this big square frame.</s>

As @andrew-reid commented, this seems to be a winding problem. Check his comment on the original answer

Using the [geoJSON from this bl.ock](https://bl.ocks.org/artidata/4a25aff39864ec088d0a61a7d31a6f44) I was able to craft this example:

https://observablehq.com/d/21415ae86b8e5610

That doesn't have everything you want, but at least shows the map. Notice how it uses a projection that fits everything into the width and height

```
  var projection = d3.geoMercator().fitSize([width, height], geoJSON);
```

Also, try not to use d3.v3, that's way too old.

Here is a working version:

https://observablehq.com/@john-guerra/geojson-singapur

Comment: Just to note: fitSize is not available for d3v3 (which you do advocate upgrading from), fit methods were introduced starting in d3v4. Also, the geojson doesn't contain a rectangle, the rectangle is an artifact of the winding order: by winding the wrong way the polygon covers the rest of the world, rather than the area of interest. Only an issue since D3 uses treats coordinates given to projections as 3D points on a sphere.

Comment: @John Alexis Guerra Gómez thanks for your input! Unfortunately I have to use the original geoJSON as the 2017 map is no longer valid. As shared by Andrew, I figured out it is a winding issue. Would it be possible for you to encode the original geoJSON with rewinding config to your example code?

Comment: Thanks @AndrewReid for the feedback. I learned something today . Sorry Grace0t0, I don't have that much free time