# Resize projection in d3JS in only one axis with a geojson map

Tags: javascript, d3.js, geojson

I have a country map that I display with d3js. I can't succeed to to make it work with this projection :

```
var projection = d3.geoConicConformal()
    .center([2.454071, 46.279229])
    .scale(0.1)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
path.projection(projection);
```

(even if others map worked)

So I'm trying to use geoIdentity to avoid position :

```
var projection = d3.geoIdentity().reflectY(true).fitExtent([[100, 100], [width-100, height-100]], geojson); //.fitSize([width,height],geojson)
    var path = d3.geoPath(projection);
```

This kind of work but the problem is that my map is wider that it should be. (In gesojson.io the map seems to have the good ratio) :

[image]

So I would like to reduce the width (X axis) to change the ratio. I tried with fitExtend and fitSize but nothing work, is there a solution to do this ?

EDIT for Andrew :

Here is what I have at first with geoConicalConformal (with fitsize/fitextend or not) :

[image]

Comment: You've tried `d3.geoConicConformal().fitSize()/fitExtent()` and this doesn't work?  Because that should work the same as it does for geoIdentity. Just don't use center/translate/scale after you use fitSize/fitExtent.

Comment: @AndrewReid I just try it and I still have the same issue I had without fitSize / fitExtend. The fact is that the map is represented by half a circle (see my edit)

Comment: The circle represents a wrongly wound feature (or features). You can rewind it ([manually](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54947126/7106086) or [with turf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49311001/7106086) ) to use a d3 geo projection. The geoIdentity doesn't make the feature too wide: it essentially is a plate carree projection by translating lat long directly to pixel, squishing it by adding a transform to the element will more approximate a Mercator projection than a conical projection such as a conic conformal projection, it'll also complicate overlaying other features.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a trick that work pretty well. Just remember that this is only a "trick".

You have to add transform scaleX (< 1 if the shape is too wide) style properties for each of your path :

```
deps.selectAll("path")
        .data(geojson.features)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr('class', 'department')
        .attr("d", path)
        .attr('id', d => "d" + d.properties.dep)
        .style('transform', 'scaleX(0.7)')
```

For me, 0.7 is perfect, you have to adjust this parameters on your project. Then, Adjust fitExtend to make the whole shape move to the right because the scaleX < 1 while make the shape move to the left. For example :

```
var projection = d3.geoIdentity().reflectY(true).fitExtent([[width * 0.3, height * 0.1], [width * 1.3, height * 0.9]], geojson);
```