# D3 Map visualization to scale the Graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am working on a London map visualization in d3 but I am unable to scale the graph. This graph shows a very small visualization.

For this map visualization, you will need to first render the GeoJson data file to be able to draw an underlying map of London suburbs.

[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <style>
                *
                {
                    font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
            
                }
                p
                {
                    font-size: 0.85em;
                }
                 .subunits
                {
                    fill: #eeeeee;
                    stroke: #333;
                    stroke-width: 0.2;
    
                }
    
               
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="map"></div>
            <script src ="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.2/d3.min.js"></script>
    
            <script src="http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    
            <script src="p.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

p.js

```
    (function() {
            var margin = { top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0},
                height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
                width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right;
        
            var svg = d3.select("#map")
                     .append("svg")
                     .attr("height",height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                     .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                     .append("g")
                     .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
        
    
            d3.queue()
            .defer(d3.json,"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/radoi90/housequest-data/master/london_boroughs.geojson")
            .await(ready)
    
        
            var projection= d3.geoAlbers()
            .center([10.5, 55.2])
            .rotate([8, 0])
            .parallels([0, 15])
            .scale(3300)
            .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
        
            var path = d3.geoPath()
                .projection(projection)
        
            
            function ready(error,data,london_stations)
            {
               
                console.log(data.features)
        
                svg.selectAll(".subunits")
                .data(data.features)
                .enter().append("path")
                .attr("class","subunits")
                .attr("d",path)
            }
            
        })();
```

Comment: You have a [winding order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54949383/7106086), using turf.js will be the easiest [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49311635/7106086). This means you cannot use utility functions such as [projection.fitSize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40940028/7106086) to automatically scale and center the map. Though, your selection of projection parameters is not making manual placement easier (set rotation to [0,0], .center([long,lat]) to a coordinate in the middle of London and increase scale until you like what you see).

Comment: As a separate point from a cartographic perspective, changing your parallels to [50,53] would be more appropriate. It's not clear why the rotation and parallels are selected as such, but it will likely create a projection that is visually different than those projections typically used for London (which I would think don't use an Albers projection at all - though I could be wrong).